# How do you make a choices field in django with an editable "other" option?

Tags: python, django

```
(
    ('one', 'One'),
    ('two', 'Two'),
    ('other', EDITABLE_HUMAN_READABLE_CHOICE),
)
```

So what I would like is a choices field with some common choices that are used frequently, but still be able to  have the option of filling in a custom human readable value.

Is this possible or is there some better way of doing this that I am completely missing?

Comment: If you consider the fact that the "other" options is mostly the last option you can just put input at the bottom, create some fancy validation and perhaps use some JavaScript for example to focus the input when the last option is clicked. The exact implementation depends on how versatile you want your app to be.

Comment: This is all just for the simple django admin site, though. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible and adding fancy JS would seem overly complex.

Comment: I agree with Manoj, but why don't you just use one plain input field (CharField) with AJAX auto-complete and avoid the extra db column? It would be easy to configure choices, even through admin and still it would be able to accept random user input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a custom `ModelForm` for admin. This form can have two fields - one that accepts a set of predefined choices and another one that accepts arbitrary values. In the `clean()` method you can ensure that only one of these has been selected.

If you are particular about how the UI should look - say, radio buttons that allow you to choose either a pre-defined value xor enter a custom value, then you may have to come up with your own custom field.

Answer (score 3):

I quick solution I used:

- used standard ModelChoice Fields
- custom Form, which added a regular Input Field for every ModelChoice Field
- custom JQuery which showed the regular Input Field only, when the last choice is selected
- in the View, when I got POST data I parsed the POST array and created the Models